# How can I pass custom props to a react Login Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that returns a Google Oauth2 button https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login

```
export default function LoginButton(props){
....
....

return (   
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId={clientId}
        onSuccess={onLoginSuccess}
        onFailure={onLoginFailure}
        cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
        isSignedIn={isSignedIn}
        render={renderProps => (
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled} fullWidth={props.fullWidth}>
          </Button>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And, I call it like this:

```
<LoginButton isLoggedIn={props.isLoggedIn} setIsLoggedIn={props.setIsLoggedIn} fullWidth={true}/>
```

However, the fullWidth never gets set to the full width. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Youre not using the `fullWidth` anywhere, where should it go?

Comment: `fullWidth={props.fullWidth}`

Comment: Ah, sorry, didnt see it. Carry on :)

Comment: Does it work when you just set it to true directly? To make sure its not something else causing the problem. So in `<Button fullWidth/>` (dont have to do `fullWidth={true}`, just `fullWidth` will do too).

Comment: What library are you using for `Button` maybe it doesn't accepts `fullWidth` prop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you need renderProps you can add custom class for that:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";

function LoginButton(props) {
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId="658977310896-knrl3gka66fldh83dao2rhgbblmd4un9.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        buttonText="Login"
        onSuccess={responseGoogle}
        onFailure={responseGoogle}
        cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
        isSignedIn={true}
        className={props.fullWidth ? "fullWidth" : ""}
        // render={(renderProps) => (
        //   <button onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled}>
        //     This is my custom Google button
        //   </button>
        // )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <LoginButton isLoggedIn={false} setIsLoggedIn={true} fullWidth={true} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-cloud-go2co

Try setting **fullWidth** props true and false

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use:

```
renderProps.fullWidth
```

instead of:

```
props.fullWidth
```